# karma/Jasmine: Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'loginController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: jasmine

My controller file :

```
define(['app', 'back123','loginService'], function (app) {
app.controller('loginController', function ($scope, $window, loginService, srvAuth) {$scope.emailValidate = function () {
        var pattern = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
        if (!pattern.test($scope.Email) ) {

           $scope.email_invalid = true;
           return false;
       }
       else {
           $scope.email_invalid = false;
           return true;
       }
    };
})
```

});

My test file:

```
define(['app', 'jquery', 'angular-mock', 'coreService', 'setterService', 'loginService','logincontroller'], function (App, $) {

describe('app', function () {
    beforeEach(module('app'));

    describe('logincontroller Email Vaidate', function () {
        var scope;
        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            $controller("loginController", {
                $scope: scope
            });
        }));


        it('sets email false', function () {
            scope.email_invalid = false;
            scope.Email = 'true';
            scope.emailValidate();
            expect(scope.email_invalid).toEqual(false);
        });
    });

});
```

});

In my browser 'Sources' tab loginCtrl file is loaded which contains logincontroller function
Still getting error

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'loginController' is not a function, got undefined
```

Please suggest

Comment: Just to add, I am using require.js to load the files

Comment: You don't need the `define` if you are loading your module in your test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I have used angularAMD, I updated the code as folows :

```
angularAMD.inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            $controller("loginController", {
                $scope: scope
            });
        });
```

Also, I included angularAMD as dependency in define module:

```
define(['app', 'jquery', 'angularAMD', 'angular-mock', 'coreService', 'setterService', 'loginService', 'loginController'], function (App, $, angularAMD) {
```